# How to download tiles to use offline

Tags: tiles, download, tile-map-service

I need to download tiles of an entire country to use offline.
I don't need a server o whatever, I just need to download tiles organised in folders (x y and z).
Should I use mapnick? Im on OSX but I can also use Windows 8.1
Which tool permit to organise tiles in such form?

Comment: Tiles of what service?

Comment: The type of tiles will greatly influence the answer.  Spatial data of all sorts can be organized into tiles--some exist only on FTP sites while others exist on WMS.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a very short question so I will try do give you an detailed answer :)

First you need to figure out how this map tiles need **to be organized**. There is the [Tile map service](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS) standard that describes how to form URLs, but there is also the [slippy map way](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_filenames) how OSM organizes the world of tiles.

Next is about **legal aspects**. Google Maps map tiles are protected by copyright and the same for all other commercial map providers, so you need to buy them. OSM tiles at the opposite CAN be published under a [free license](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ), but they don't have to. Also there might be technical restrictions on such kind of bulk downloading. For example the osm.org tile servers have [tile usage policies](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) to protect the volunteered infrastructure. Otherwise your requests might [get blocked](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Blocked_applications).

If you keep this notes in mind, you might be happy with tools like (newest!) [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mobile_Atlas_Creator) or  [JTileDownloader](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JTileDownloader).
As you like to transfer a huge amount of tiles, that will take very long due to this technical restrictions, you might consider to setup a complete local [rendering stack](http://switch2osm.org/), or use [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) as a Desktop solution (at least KOSMOS had the feature to create tiles)